# Ubuntu Mosquitto broker websocket is not working

Tags: websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm new at IoT & MQTT communication protocol. I'm trying to connect my broker which runs at Amazon Ec2 from my Vue web app via Websockets. I have started mosquitto with:

```
root@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:~# mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf
1618518468: mosquitto version 1.6.7 starting
1618518468: Config loaded from /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf.
1618518468: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 1883.
1618518468: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
1618518468: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
```

/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf file contains:

```
listener 1883 
protocol mqtt 
allow_anonymous true 

listener 9001 
protocol websockets 
allow_anonymous true
```

My test js file is:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');
var count =0;
var client  = mqtt.connect("mqtt://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx",{clientId:"mqttjs01"});
console.log("connected flag  " + client.connected);

//handle incoming messages
client.on('message',function(topic, message, packet){
    console.log("message is "+ message);
    console.log("topic is "+ topic);
});


client.on("connect",function(){ 
console.log("connected  "+ client.connected);

})
//handle errors
client.on("error",function(error){
console.log("Can't connect" + error);
process.exit(1)});
//publish
function publish(topic,msg,options){
console.log("publishing",msg);

if (client.connected == true){
    
client.publish(topic,msg,options);

}
count+=1;
if (count==2) //ens script
    clearTimeout(timer_id); //stop timer
    client.end();   
}

//////////////


var options={
retain:true,
qos:1};
var topic="acs";
var message="test message";
var topic_list=["topic2","topic3","topic4"];
var topic_o={"topic22":0,"topic33":1,"topic44":1};
console.log("subscribing to topics");
client.subscribe(topic,{qos:0}); //single topic
client.subscribe(topic_list,{qos:1}); //topic list
client.subscribe(topic_o); //object
var timer_id=setInterval(function(){publish(topic,message,options);},5000);
//notice this is printed even before we connect
console.log("end of script");
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
New client connected from 176.xxx.xxx.xx as mqttjs01 (p2, c1, k60).
1618518546: Socket error on client mqttjs01, disconnecting.
```

I have installed libwebsockets, I have tried with various mosquitto versions. Current version is: 1.6.7.

Is there any problem with my client or broker? How can I fix this?

Comment: Sharing your mosquitto configuration file and the code you’re using to connect would make it a lot more likely that you’d get help. As it is you’re asking us to guess how you have it set up and how you’re using it.

Comment: Please include the actual code in the question, not a link to a 3rd party site.

Comment: Your connect() call says "mqtt://xx.xx.xx.xx", yet your question is about websockets, which would be "ws://xx.xx.xx.xx"   Check out Steve's Internet Guide for MQTT over WebSockets:  http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-websockets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the `publish()` function the if statement is missing enclosing braces so it doesn't do what you think it does.

```
function publish(topic,msg,options){
console.log("publishing",msg);

if (client.connected == true){
    
client.publish(topic,msg,options);

}
count+=1;
if (count==2) //ens script
    clearTimeout(timer_id); //stop timer
    client.end();   
}
```

Lets fix the indentation so we can see more clearly.

```
function publish(topic,msg,options){
  console.log("publishing",msg);

  if (client.connected == true){  
    client.publish(topic,msg,options);
  }

  count+=1;
  if (count==2) //ens script
    clearTimeout(timer_id); //stop timer
  
  client.end();   
}
```

As you can see `client.end()` will ALWAYS be called when ever `publish()` is called. If you only want to publish twice you need to wrap the 2 statements in the braces (this is not python where whitespace has meaning)

```
  if (count==2) { //ens script
    clearTimeout(timer_id); //stop timer
    client.end();  
  }
```

You really should indent all your code properly it will make it much easier to read and to spot errors like this.

Also as @JDAllen mentioned you are not making use of the WebSocket connection, unless this code is running in the browser, where the sandbox will force it to be a WebSocket connection even if you specify `mqtt://` as the schema in the URL, and you will have to include the port number to make it actually connect. e.g.

```
ws://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9001
```